# Error while running models in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

This is my Report model

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Report extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['ApiKey', 'Success', 'Error', 'Token', 'Password'];

    protected $hidden = ['Token'];

}
```

And in my controller i have this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;  

use App\Report;
```

I don't get any error, absolutely nothing happens, but I tested it with running `die()` command through code, and program stops in `$report = new Report`

On my home computer XAMPP, this code work, but it won't on remote server.

This is not only for this model, its for all models in code.

I have Apache, Ubuntu, PHP 5.5 with Lumen

Comment: What error message do you get? Are you sure the files are uploaded and have thenright permissions set?

Comment: I don't get any error, absolutely nothing happens, but i tested it with die() command, and program stops in $report = new Report or while creating any other model

Comment: On the srver, please go to the directory the models are in and run "ls -al"and tell me which user and which permissions are set for the files. / one model. Is it a web app? In lumen.log is nothing too?

Comment: user -> root, permissions ->  -rw-r--r--

Comment: yes, mobile phone calling online API to return some json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above the user is wrong and lumen can't access the model files due to missing permissions. You should change the user to `www-data` and set 775 permissions on the application's folder:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data <path/to/application>
sudo chmod -R 775 <path/to/application>
```